# Calling onDataChange() by setting value to itself? Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I was basically wondering if I set the value of a variable in a Firebase database to itself aka turn a "Hello World" into a "Hello World" in some android studio code, would a ValueEventListener consider this a change and run the onDataChange() function?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not trigger the listener.  This should be easy for you to test for yourself.

Comment: Do you know of a way to trigger the listener without changing the contents of the Firebase database?

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible.  Just store the prior snapshot somewhere if you want to remember what it was for a later time.